# Why the jquery prop() method can not get the the element's value property

Tags: jquery, prop

I have several `li` element in page:

```
<li value="a">a</li>
<li value="b">b</li>
<li value="c">c</li>
<li value="d">d</li>
```

the I want get the value property when hover on it:

```
$(function () {
    $('li').live('mouseover', function () {
        console.log($(this).prop('value'));                             
    })
});
```

but the result is always `0`,then I try the `attr()` method, it still can not work ,how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`li` elements do not have a `value` property.

For storing your own meta-data against an element you should use HTML5 `data-*` attributes:

```
<li data-value="a">a</li>
<li data-value="b">b</li>
<li data-value="c">c</li>
<li data-value="d">d</li>
```

Then use the jquery [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to retrieve them:

```
$(function () {
    $('li').live('mouseover', function () {
        console.log($(this).data('value'));                             
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I replicated this in a fiddle, even doesn't work using `.val` either. Probably because `value` is only designed for form fields. A solution is to change the `value` to a data attribute, like so:

```
<li data-value="a">a</li>
<li data-value="b">b</li>
<li data-value="c">c</li>
<li data-value="d">d</li>​

$(function () {
    $('li').live('mouseover', function () {
        alert($(this).data("value"));                             
    });
});​
```

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7X5hj/)

Answer (score 0):

A `<li>` element cannot have a `value` attribute. If you want to define your own custom attributes, prefix them with `data-`.

```
<li data-value="a">a</li>
<li data-value="b">b</li>
<li data-value="c">c</li>
<li data-value="d">d</li>
```

Then change the name in your JavaScript code:

```
$(function () {
    $('li').live('mouseover', function () {
        console.log($(this).prop('data-value'));                             
    });
});
```

jQuery also lets you easily access `data-` attributes using [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

```
        console.log($(this).data('value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead You can do this**

```
$(function () 
{
    $('li').hover( function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('value'));                             
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**It Works Checked !!**

```
$(function ()
{
    $('li').hover( function () {
        alert($(this).text());                             
    })
});
```